# Why does my jQuery script run only once?

Tags: jquery

I have radio buttons that simply have "YES" and "NO" as options.

```
<input name="paperAvailable" type="radio" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input name="paperAvailable" type="radio" value="No"> No
```

I wish to hide a couple of table rows (under the class name 'paperavailable' with jQuery script when the option "No" is selected, and show the rows again when the user select 'Yes'

Somehow, the function only seem to work once on page load. Is it because I placed the functions in the document.ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.paperavailable').hide();


//Paper Available columns
$("input[name='paperAvailable']").click(function() {
    if ($("input[name='paperAvailable']").val() == "YES") { 
        $(".paperavailable").show();
    }

    else { 
    $(".paperavailable").hide("slow");
        }

});

});
```

Comment: You copy pasted this correctly? I think in the if the "YES" should be just "Yes"

Comment: Np, also I think you might want to read up on the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function as it might be better suited for this type of task, and you will save some hairpulling by knowing about that

Answer (score 2):

2 problems

1. The string comparison is case sensitive - you have the value set to `Yes`, but in comparison you are testing against `YES`
2. `$("input[name='paperAvailable']").val()` will always return the value of first input element with name `paperAvailable`, instead you need to get the value of the checked element

you need to test the checked radio box

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $paper = $('.paperavailable').hide();
    //Paper Available columns
    var $radios = $("input[name='paperAvailable']").click(function () {
        if ($radios.filter(':checked').val() == "Yes") {
            $paper.show();
        } else {
            $paper.hide("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bCDG3/)

Comment: May be worth explicitly noting that string comparisons are case-sensitive, so having a value of `Yes` on your radio button and comparing that to `YES` will never evaluate to true.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist it is fixed... noticed it later